# What MPL PayPal.setIsRememberMe() is for?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the following code to initialize the paypal instance (MPL):

```
private void initLibrary() {
  PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
  if( null == pp ){
    pp = PayPal.initWithAppID( this, getString( R.string.paypal_app_id ), PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX );
    pp.setLanguage( Locale.getDefault().toString() );
    pp.setFeesPayer( PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER );
    pp.setShippingEnabled( true );
  }
}
```

each time I open the paypal-page by:

```
PayPalAdvancedPayment ppap = new PayPalAdvancedPayment();
ppap.setCurrencyType( a.getCurrency() );
....
Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout( ppap, this );
startActivityForResult( checkoutIntent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT );
```

I get the login dialog 1st and only after entering the password I can pay. 
I'd like to make 1-click payment w/o entering the login info each time.

I saw, that there's a `PayPal.setIsRememberMe(boolean)` method which seems to accomplish that. Although, if I call it, I'm getting "android_10898" error on the login page.

So, I'd like to know what exactly the `setIsRememberMe()` method is doing and how can I achieve the 1-click payment?

Anybody?

Comment: hello...i am also facing the same problem.Getting the same error. Have you found the solution for this

Comment: no, no solution yet...